# Using ArrayList.indexOf when looking for values within an object

Tags: java, arraylist, getter

I have a branch class that has an arraylist of customer objects. In the branch class I want to `addTransaction` for a given customer name, but first I want to check if the customer exists, then add the transaction.

```
private boolean customerExists(String customerName) {
    for (int i = 0; i < customers.size(); i++) {
        if(customers.get(i).getCustomerName().equalsIgnoreCase(customerName)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}


private int customerPosition(String customerName) {
    for (int i = 0; i < customers.size(); i++) {
        if(customers.get(i).getCustomerName().equalsIgnoreCase(customerName)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}



public void addTransaction(String customerName, Double transactionValue) {
    if(customerExists(customerName) == false) {
        System.out.println("Customer with name " + customerName + " not found");
    } else {
        customers.get(customerPosition(customerName)).addTransaction(transactionValue);
    }
}
```

I know this code will work, however I'm concious that I have to do 2 loops through the arraylist to check it exists, and get its position. Which seems inefficient

I know the `indexOf` method would be useful in `addTransaction`, but I'm not sure how I use it if I am looking for a specific value inside the object, and not the object itself i.e. I'm not looking for the Customer object, I'm looking for a value within the object. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Thanks everyone, these answers are fantastic.

Comment: Use .equals() to verify indexof

Comment: One could also make use of a `Map<String, Customer>` and add uppercase / lowercase names to it (for case insensitive comparision), then get a customer by name (also uppercase / lowercase). This addresses your concern for inefficiency.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot, in general, do any better than just looping through the list to find a value.

In terms of the code duplication, replace the body of `customerExists` with:

```
return customerPosition() >= 0;
```

And, in `addTransaction()`, store the result of `customerPosition()` in a variable, and use `thatVariable >= 0` instead of calling `customerExists()`.

If you are using Java 8+, you could use streams:

```
Optional<Customer> cust = customers.stream().filter(c -> c.getCustomerName().equals(customerName)).findFirst();
```

Then you don't have to worry about using the index at all.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Multiple for loop, use single for loop and get the customer object and use that,

```
private Customer getCustomerUsingName(String customerName) {
    for (int i = 0; i < customers.size(); i++) {
        if(customers.get(i).getCustomerName().equalsIgnoreCase(customerName)) {
            return customers.get(i);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Use the Customer in your method

```
public void addTransaction(String customerName, Double transactionValue) {
    Customer customer = getCustomerUsingName(customerName)

    if(customer == null) {
        return;
    }
    customer.addTransaction(transactionValue);
}
```

Comment: Good way while I would favor `Optional` to `null`.

Comment: Additionally, there is no reason to use an indexed loop there. An enhanced for loop is neater.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you could use some mutant variant of 'indexOf', it would not improve efficiency.  To find data in an unsorted array, you have to traverse the array looking for it.  That is inherent in the choice of an array to store the data.

But why are you using customerExists at all?  customerPosition executes exactly the same logic.  You need only call it once.

```
   int pos = customerPosition(...);
   if (pos >= 0) 
      customers.get(pos).addTransaction(...);
   else 
      ... does not exist ...
```

Answer (score 0):

use `customerPosition` method for check exist `Customer`

```
public void addTransaction(String customerName, Double transactionValue) {
    final int index = customerPosition(customerName);
    if(index == -1) {
        System.out.println("Customer with name " + customerName + " not found");
    } else {
        customers.get(index).addTransaction(transactionValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a HashMap instead,

generally the ArrayList is quicker than the HashTable in some cases, but when you have to lookup for an element the HashTable (using the key to search) is faster than the ArrayList, you can use it :

```
HashMap<String, Customer> myCustomers = new HashMap<String, Customer>();
myCustomers.put("NameID_1", customerObject_1);
myCustomers.put("NameID_2", customerObject_2);
myCustomers.put("NameID_3", customerObject_3);
myCustomers.put("NameID_4", customerObject_4);

System.out.println(myCustomers.get("NameID_1"));
// just check if the customer exists in your Map
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the first answer from Andy Turner. After `findFirst()` you can apply `ifPresent` consumer which will add the transaction.

```
customers.stream()
        .filter(c -> c.getCustomerName().equals(customerName))
        .findFirst()
        .ifPresent(customer -> customer.addTransaction(transactionValue));
```

If in the future, you will need to add transaction to all customers that match the filter predicate, you can use `forEach` and pass the consumer from previous example.

```
customers.stream()
        .filter(c -> c.getCustomerName().equals(customerName))
        .forEach(customer -> customer.addTransaction(transactionValue));
```

In case if you use Java version bellow 8, your loops could be slightly improved. You can have a single loop

```
Iterator it = customers.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Customer customer = it.next();
    if (customerPredicate.test(customer)) { // your if condition
        customer.addTransaction(transactionValue); // your consumer.
        break; // If you need to change only first customer.
    }
}
```

A technical note

**Stream** has **forEach** and **peek** methods. If you need to apply your consumer to all elements of the stream, and still have a new stream (a lazy operation) - use `peek`. If you want to apply your consumer for all elements and terminate the stream (you do not need a stream anymore) - use terminal operation - `forEach`.